# Solution of the differential equation $(1+y^2-x^2)y'=\frac{1}{x}, y(1)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Solution of the differential equation $(1+y^2-x^2)y'=\frac{1}{x}, y(1)=1$ is the differential equation have solution ? and is this solution is exist?

I am trying to prove by using picard's theorem

here given ODE is $(1+y^2-x^2)y'=\frac{1}{x}$

then $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{(1+y^2-x^2)x}\Rightarrow |f(x,y)|=|\frac{1}{(1+y^2-x^2)x}|$  from here how to processed

Answer (score 1):

$(1+y^2-x^2)y'=\dfrac{1}{x}$ with $y(1)=1$

$(1+y^2-x^2)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{x}$ with $y(1)=1$

$\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{dx}{dy}=1+y^2-x^2$ with $x(1)=1$

Let $u=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dy}=-\dfrac{2}{x^3}\dfrac{dx}{dy}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{x^2}{2}\dfrac{du}{dy}=1+y^2-x^2$ with $u(1)=1$

$\dfrac{du}{dy}=2-\dfrac{2(y^2+1)}{x^2}$ with $u(1)=1$

$\dfrac{du}{dy}=2-2(y^2+1)u$ with $u(1)=1$

$\dfrac{du}{dy}+2(y^2+1)u=2$ with $u(1)=1$

I.F. $=e^{\int2(y^2+1)~dy}=e^{\frac{2y^3}{3}+2y}$

$\therefore\dfrac{d\left(ue^{\frac{2y^3}{3}+2y}\right)}{dy}=2e^{\frac{2y^3}{3}+2y}$ with $u(1)=1$

$u=2e^{-\frac{2y^3}{3}-2y}\int e^{\frac{2y^3}{3}+2y}~dy+Ce^{-\frac{2y^3}{3}-2y}$ with $u(1)=1$

$Ce^{-\frac{2}{3}-2}=1$

$C=e^\frac{8}{3}$

$\therefore u=2e^{-\frac{2y^3}{3}-2y}\int_1^ye^{\frac{2y^3}{3}+2y}~dy+e^{\frac{8}{3}-2y-\frac{2y^3}{3}}$

$\dfrac{1}{x^2}=2e^{-\frac{2y^3}{3}-2y}\int_1^ye^{\frac{2y^3}{3}+2y}~dy+e^{\frac{8}{3}-2y-\frac{2y^3}{3}}$

$x^2=\dfrac{1}{2e^{-\frac{2y^3}{3}-2y}\int_1^ye^{\frac{2y^3}{3}+2y}~dy+e^{\frac{8}{3}-2y-\frac{2y^3}{3}}}$